# Counting cases?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I don't have a background on probabilities but i do want to get the rule to solve the following problem and similar ones .

Let's say we have a 2x2 matrix , in which every element could be either 1 or 0 .
like :

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 \\ 0& 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1 \\1& 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0& 1 \\ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}\ldots$$

Those were 3 of 16 cases we could get , right ? How do we calculate cases in this kind of problems ? What do we call the study of this kinda probabilities .

Comment: Yes, there are $2^4$ possibilities, and for an $n\times n$ matrix there are $2^{n^2}$ possibilities.

Comment: because you each of the element has two possibilities 0 ,or 1 , so the total number of cases is 2*2*2*2 = 16

Comment: thanx , i get this completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We call this combinatorics.  If you search the site for that tag you will find *many* questions and answers.  Generally, if you have several independent choices to make, the total number of options is the product of the number of options at each point.  In your example, you have two choices four times, so the total number is $2^4=16$

Comment: Thanx , i get it completely